# Como retirar um item específico de um array em vba?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

No meu código eu tenho um array, e ao realizar uma validação (os intervalos não podem ser maiores do que 6) eu precisaria excluir do array os itens que não atendem à esta validação.

```
    If tempos(t) > 0 And tempos(t + 1) > 0 Then
        If tempos(t + 1) - tempos(t) > 6 Then
            Debug.Print (tempos(t + 1))
        End If
    End If
```

O meu array **tempos** precisaria conter apenas os valores que passaram nas validações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você pode atribuir os valores que a um outro array e ir redimensionando ele com a preservação dos valores anteriores.

```
    Sub teste()

Dim tempos() As Integer
Dim novoArray() As Integer

Dim tamanho As Integer
tamanho = 20

ReDim tempos(1 To tamanho) As Integer
Dim i, t As Integer

For t = 1 To tamanho
tempos(t) = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 50)
Next

i = 1

For t = 1 To tamanho - 1
    If tempos(t) > 0 And tempos(t + 1) > 0 Then
    
        If tempos(t + 1) - tempos(t) > 6 Then
            ReDim Preserve novoArray(1 To i + 1)
            novoArray(i) = tempos(t + 1)
            i = i + 1
        Else
            
        End If
        
    End If
Next t

For t = 1 To i - 1
texto = texto & novoArray(t) & ", "
Next
MsgBox texto

End Sub
```

Espero ter ajudado!